# Send multiple paths to one route without redirect function

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I am updating my website to a Meteor application with iron-router, and need to change my urls. The old scheme had capitalized page names like this:

```
mysite.com/Contact
```

but I've changed everything to be lowercase:

```
mysite.com/contact
```

That contact route isn't complicated, so it's set up like this:

```
this.route('contact');
```

but I want the `/Contact` url to be redirected. I know I could just do this:

```
this.route('Contact', {
    onBeforeAction: function() {
        Router.go('contact');
    }
});
```

but it's so much messier. I'd prefer to do something like this:

```
this.route('contact', {
    path: ['/contact', '/Contact']
});
```

where the route simply is mapped to multiple paths.

Is there a feature like this? Or is my `onBeforeAction` the best I'm going to get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router/blob/devel/DOCS.md#dynamic-path-segments

You can use a Regular Expression for your path segment (see the last example in the Dynamic Path Segments link).

Your path would be:

```
this.route('contact', {
    path: /contact/i
});
```

Where the 'i' after the forward-slash is the regular expression modifier to be case insensitive allowing you to accept any variation of 'contact' (whether cOntact, Contact, or conTACT).

See http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_i.asp for details on the RegEx modifier.

Comment: Smart! Can't believe I didn't think of that.